# File copying issue while converting to LPCTSTR

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-c++

```
// Convert to a wchar_t*

size_t origsize = strlen(toChar) + 1;

const size_t newsize = 100;

size_t convertedChars = 0;

wchar_t wcstring[newsize];

mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, origsize, toChar, _TRUNCATE);

wcscat_s(wcstring, L"\\*.*\0");

wcout << wcstring << endl; // C:\Documents and Settings\softnotions\Desktop\Release\*.*



SHFILEOPSTRUCT sf;

memset(&sf,0,sizeof(sf));

sf.hwnd = 0;

sf.wFunc = FO_COPY;

//sf.pFrom =wcstring;  /* when giving wcstring i am not getting answer */

 sf.pFrom = L"C:\\Documents and Settings\\softnotions\\Desktop\\Release\\*.*\0";

   wcout << sf.pFrom  <<endl;   // C:\Documents and Settings\softnotions\Desktop\Release\*.*
```

Both `wcstring`  and `sf.pFrom` are same then why not gettng answer when assigning `sf.pFrom =wcstring;`

Comment: First of all it is MFC and not MVC.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "I am not getting answer"? It is assigning or something else is happening?

Comment: wcscat_s(wcstring, L"\\*.*");
wcstring[wstrlen(wcstring) + 1] = 0;

what header i have to use to take wstrlen

Answer (score 1):

`SHFILEOPSTRUCT` requires `pFrom` and `pTo` to be [double-null-terminated strings](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2010/02/18/9965469.aspx).

The string literal you assign to `pFrom` has an embedded `\0`, so the string is double-null-terminated.

When you call `wcscat_s`, the embedded `\0` is interpreted as the end of the string to append, so the resulting string is not double-null-terminated.

As you say in your comment, you can do this (although the function you need is `wcslen`):

```
wcscat_s(wcstring, L"\\*.*");
wcstring[wcslen(wcstring) + 1] = 0;
```